# Apache Kafka server not starting

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, java

I have installed the standalone version of zookeeper and it works perfectly fine and the server starts. But I am not able to start the kafka server and the zookeeper instance that comes with the kafka package.All my commands are correct and the logDir and dataDir fields are changed in my properties files to the correct directories.My machine is windows 10 64bit.I also tried installing the binary version but it is not starting. It says that java is not able to load the main class log files.I also downloaded the batch files again but still the same error.

There is no proper documentation online for setup on windows.My friend tried the same on linux and it worked in the first attempt.
Any kind of help or links are appreciated.
Thank you